# ObservableList returns sublist that matches

Tags: java, observablelist

I'm not quite sure how to word this question so bear with me.

I have an `ObservableList` of user defined objects with a couple getter methods such as:

```
public String getName() { return this.name; }
public int getId() { return this.id; }
```

What I want to do is be able to return a sublist from my main observable list by searching for substrings. So if I have some classes that contain these names:

```
car
carrol
castro
bret
```

How would I go about getting an `ObservableList<MyClass>` of all the objects where the name parameter, retrieved by `getName()`, contains a substring of "ca" as in:

```
car
carrol
castro
```

or a substring of "car" as in:

```
car
carrol
```

Here is my method so far:

```
 public ObservableList<Part> searchBySubstring(String sub, ObservableList<Part> full){
    ObservableList<Part> newParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < full.size(); i++){
        if(full.get(i).getPartName().contains(sub))
            newParts.add(full.get(i));
    }
    return newParts;
}
```

Comment: You can create another method that would do that or perform that task.

Comment: Can you paste your whole code here, I can then update it and post the answer

Comment: *paste your whole code here* - well maybe not **all**

Comment: I was mainly looking for a way to do it with built in functionality, I updated the OP with non-built in way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking to simply create a "snapshot" of the original `ObservableList` then what you're already doing is the way to do it. You could change the code to use a for-each loop or streams, but I'd say that's more of a stylistic choice.

For-Each loop:

```
ObservableList<Part> search(String sub, ObservableList<Part> full) {
    ObservableList<Part> result = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Part part : full) {
        if (part.getPartName().contains(sub)) {
            result.add(part);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Streams:

```
ObservableList<Part> search(String sub, ObservableList<Part> full) {
    return full.stream()
            .filter(part -> part.getPartName().contains(sub))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
}
```

However, if you're looking to have an `ObservableList` that updates as the original `ObservableList` changes, use a [`FilteredList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html). In this case, you'd only need to create the `FilteredList` *once* and update the `Predicate` as needed.

```
String sub = ...;
ObservableList<Part> full = ...;
FilteredList<Part> filtered = full.filtered(part -> part.getPartName().contains(sub));
// or use new FilteredList<>(...);

// Then, to "re-search" the list...
String newSub = ...;
filtered.setPredicate(part -> part.getPartName().contains(newSub));
```

The `FilteredList` will update as elements are added to and removed from the original `ObservableList`. If you want it to update when the name of a `Part` (already in the list) changes then you need to do two things:

1. Have `Part` expose `partName` as an `Observable`, such as `StringProperty`.
2. Construct the original `ObservableList` with an extractor via [`observableArrayList(Callback)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)) or [`observableList(List,Callback)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList(java.util.List,javafx.util.Callback)).

An example of using an extractor:

```
ObservableList<Part> parts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        part -> new Observable[]{part.partNameProperty()});
```

The `Callback` is a `Callback<E, Observable[]>`.